# How can I determine the dimensionality of a list?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

How do I determine the dimensionality of a list programmatically? Thanks.

Comment: Lists are *always* one-dimensional.

Comment: Lists are *not* arrays: the entries in a (nested) list don't have to be the same structure. `[a, [b,c]]` is a legal list, but doesn't really have a dimensionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming uniformity:

```
dims = []
while isinstance(matrix, list) and matrix is not None:
    dims.append(len(matrix))
    matrix = matrix[0]
number_of_dimensions = len(dims)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Happy to help. If you like an answer, consider upvoting/accepting

Comment: Sorry about the delay - went to watch the new Spiderman movie. Just got back to my desk at work. Depending on the version of python, `None` objects can be of every type. `isinstance(None, list)` returns `True` in some versions. I wrote this code to be version independent. It should work with python 2.x (can't be sure about 3.x)

Answer (score 7):

For a straightforward list, you can get its length with `len`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> len(l)
5
```

For matrices, which are most easily represented as nested lists, you can get the length of the first sub-list, e.g.:

```
>>> matrix = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8],
    [9, 10]]
>>> len(matrix)
5
>>> len(matrix[0])
2
```

Taking into account JBernardo's comment, define a simple `iterable` helper:

```
>>> def iterable(x):
    if isinstance(x, basestring): return False
    try:
        iter(x)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    return True

>>> iterable(4)
False
>>> iterable([1, 2, 3])
True
```

Then we can recursively define the `dimensionality` function:

```
>>> def dimensionality(l):
    if not iterable(l): return 0
    return 1 + dimensionality(l[0])

>>> dimensionality(0)
0
>>> dimensionality([1, 2, 3])
1
>>> dimensionality([[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]])
2
>>> dimensionality([[[1,2],[2,3]], [[2,3],[3,4]], [[3,4],[4,5]]])
3
```

Instead of `iterable` you could do `isinstance(x, list)` or whatever other check you want. Edited to exclude strings to avoid `dimensionality('lol')` infinite loop.

Comment: Maybe OP meant the number of dimensions.

Comment: `dimensionality('lol')` -> infinite loop. Make sure to exclude strings.